# how to  call setInput() of ImageReader class?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

How to  call `setInput` of `ImageReader` class?
Below is my code:

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(newByteArrayInputStream(cipherData));    
Iterator<ImageReader> readers=ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
Iterator<ImageReader> readers=ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
System.out.println("readers="+readers);
```

Comment: Try to code iterators as what they are: use `hasNext()` and `next()` to get the next `ImageReader` instance of readers; use that instance to access `setInput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean calling the method on the `ImageReader`s contained in your readers variable, you could loop over them:

```
for (Iterator<ImageReader> it=ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis); it.hasNext();) {
    ImageReader reader = it.next();
    readers.setInput(someObject);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you only want the first element:

```
Iterator<ImageReader> it=ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
ImageReader reader = null;
if (it.hasNext()) {
    reader = it.next();
}
//you probably want to check for null here to make sure there was one element
```

Comment: suppose there is only one element and there is no need of loop.Then what will be the code

Comment: @shree ImageIO.getImageReaders() always return an iterator. It still needs hasNext to check for an empty iterator (it means no suitable image reader for decoding the image). Iterator doesn't usually return size() or length() to tell how many suitable ImageReaders it can get. But, a few Iterators have been overridden to provide this kind of knowledge (in a collection), breaking their intended design. http://www.coderanch.com/t/408364/java/java/Find-size-Iterator-thing or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720195/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-count-length-size-of-an-iterator