# How do i get the Iterator size without looping?

Tags: java, iterator

How do I get the Iterator size without looping ? Is there anyway to do this ?

```
Iterator<String> keys = Map.keySet().iterator();
```

Now I want the size of Keys just forget the `Map.keySet()` here.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720195/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-count-length-size-of-an-iterator

Answer (score 3):

An Iterator just give you a method of walking over a Collection, so the "size of the Iterator" is the size of the collection it iterates over.  In this case just use Set's (or any other Collection) built in [size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#size%28%29) method :

```
int size = Map.keySet().size();
```

If you are in a situation where you just have access to the Iterator but need the underlying Collection's size I think you'll need to talk to the one giving you just that iterator, and either get access to the Collection, or get the size of the Collection.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator is an implementation of [java.util.Iterator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). This interface does not provide any method to know the size of it's implementations (In fact these implementations don't need to have a size property). If you need an Iterator with a size, and a method to get it, you should build your own implementation.

However, if what you need is the size of the collection the iterator traverses, fvu answer is correct.